# How to avoid http code 204?

Tags: scala, web-scraping

The information I'm interested in from a website I'm scraping comes in the form of a Json from an Ajax call. However, when I make the call, it sometimes returns with a 204 - no content - Http response code, giving me no data at all.

Is there any way, from the client side, to force the server to always return content, like setting up a header, or by some other way?

I'm using the Scala Play WS API.For example,

```
WS.url(url).withQueryParameters(queryParameters)
.withHeaders("User-Agent" -> "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)...",
"X-Requested-With" -> "XMLHttpRequest",
"Cookie" -> "cookie1=1; cookie2=2;...")
.get()
```

**Update: Ajax payload**

AJAX CAPTURE Chrome extension data:

```
$.get(url).done (showResult).fail(showError);

{
  "frameId": 0,
  "method": "GET",
  "parentFrameId": -1,
  "requestId": "122389",
  "tabId": 2432,
  "timeStamp": 1444493900946.029,
  "type": "xmlhttprequest",
  "url": url
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> it sometimes returns with a 204 - no content

Better you provide info of what server do you request.

There might be many reasons why you do not get content of your request.

1. The server is not able to form dynamic content for a response because of being overloaded and it's set this way to return an empty content (instead of raising timeout issue).
2. The security service on a target server finds out/suspects you are a bad requester (bot, suspicious IP, etc.) and instead of banning and returning code `400` it returns nothing namely code `204`.

   - Special case here is that server might require ONLY ajax calls to be made  while you seemingly do regular request. See this [post](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax) and how to [add it to curl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10996918/1230477).
3. The server makes some special check of your request and cause you miss some parameters (GET parameters, POST payload, cookie and other) you get nothing.

If you want to fix it on the target server - turn to the site owners for it.

### Update: Ajax payload in Stackoverflow request analysis

Consider the following shot from *AJAX CAPTURE* Chrome extention:
[image]

As you can see the whole request payload consists of the form data **1.** and some service info, total constituting a payload object - **2.** 
So, the **2.** includes the **1.** as you can see in the shot. So for your target server you need to explore/investigate the actual ajax requests a browser makes and simulate similar ones.

Notes:

1. `requestId` is obvious the stackoverflow inner request counter and therefore it's not easy to be crafted/generated/simutaled.
2. `timeStamp` is obvious the stackoverflow timing value (plus smth. else), so it might be tricky to find an algorithm that forms them. Takes some trials taken over time to find out the algorithm.

Comment: I would rather not disclose the server I'm scraping. On your points:
 1. Sometimes it's the first request after a while that gets the 204, so I wouldn't think it gets overloaded.
 3. I've tried the same parameters (cookies, etc.) as the original client and I still get 204.
 2. This one makes more sense. I will try  simulating an AJAX call.

Comment: @LuisGaleana, try to simulate AJAX call. Would you post in your question *how* do you compose your request (incl. cookie)? This might help to understand your situation.

Comment: @LuisGaleana, what platform do you use for your scraper (Win, Linux, OSX)?

Comment: The AJAX call didn't work. I literally tried to make the call in the exact same way, with no success. I use Ubuntu.

Comment: @LuisGaleana, if Ajax simulating does not work... have you compared your ajax request (incl. all its parameters) with the real ajax call the web browser makes to that server? See [the chrome extention](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-ajax-capture/hgicjmfpmakeejdfemjhokokaijfdjng) for ajax monitoring...

Comment: This is the only code that I got: $.get(url).done (showResult).fail(showError). What is the other data at the bottom?

Comment: @LuisGaleana do you mean "data at the bottom" of the AJAX CAPTURE extention?

Comment: As I understand 2. is the whole request payload that I need to send to the server, right? I should include all the fields shown in the extension, for my ajax call, right?

Comment: @LuisGaleana, I was wrong! `2.` is just the inner representation of the xhr of the AJAX CAPTURE ext. The real request is `1.` You might check it with any other sniffing tool, ex. [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-sniffer/ndfgffclcpdbgghfgkmooklaendohaef).